# Redirect index.html to root htaccess and non www to www?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, redirect

I have written this code is this right or wrong?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.cogxim.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.cogxim.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ http://www.cogxim.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify like this to redirect non-www traffic to www

```
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*/index.html
    RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ http://www.cogxim.com/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cogxim.com
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.cogxim.com/$1 [R=301,L
```